# how to update a row based on another row with same id

Tags: apache-spark-sql

With Spark dataframe, I want to update a row value based on other rows with same id.

For example,
I have records below,

```
id,value
1,10
1,null
1,null
2,20
2,null
2,null
```

I want to get the result as below

```
id,value
1,10
1,10
1,10
2,20
2,20
2,20
```

To summarize, the value column is null in some rows, I want to update them if there is another row with same id which has valid value.

In sql, I can simply write a update sentence with inner-join, but I didn't find the same way in Spark-sql.

update combineCols a
  inner join combineCols b
    on a.id = b.id
set a.value = b.value
(this is how I do it in sql)

Comment: What if there are multiple values for a single ID? For example, if instead of id 1 having values as (10, null, null), had it been (10,30, null), what should have had happened?

Comment: it can only be one value or null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use window to do this(in pyspark):

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

# create dataframe
df = sc.parallelize([
    [1,10],
    [1,None],
    [1,None],
    [2,20],
    [2,None],
    [2,None],
]).toDF(('id', 'value'))

window = Window.partitionBy('id').orderBy(F.desc('value'))
df \
    .withColumn('value', F.first('value').over(window)) \
    .show()
```

Results:

```
+---+-----+
| id|value|
+---+-----+
|  1|   10|
|  1|   10|
|  1|   10|
|  2|   20|
|  2|   20|
|  2|   20|
+---+-----+
```

You can use the same functions in scala.

Comment: thanks:) I also found a solution by using groupby


val df2 = df1.filter(!isnan($"value")).groupBy("id").agg(mean("value").as("update_value"))
val result = df1.join(df2,Seq("id"),"inner").selectExpr("id","update_value")


Is there a better way instead of using mean function in this case?

Comment: If there are multiple value for the same id for example 1,10 and 1,20 then all rows with the 1 id have value of 15. as i understand from your explanation you dont want it. And What you expect to happen if all values are null for the same id?

Comment: if all values are null, it will remain as null, and there is only one possible value if it is not null

Comment: If all values are null it become 0 in your solution. You can use first function for all these cases.

Answer (score 1):

Let's use SQL method to solve this issue -

```
myValues = [(1,10),(1,None),(1,None),(2,20),(2,None),(2,None)]
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(myValues,['id','value'])

df.registerTempTable('table_view')
df1=sqlContext.sql(
    'select id, sum(value) over (partition by id) as value from table_view'
)
df1.show()
+---+-----+
| id|value|
+---+-----+
|  1|   10|
|  1|   10|
|  1|   10|
|  2|   20|
|  2|   20|
|  2|   20|
+---+-----+
```

**Caveat:** Thos code assumes that there is only one `non-null` value for any particular `id`. When we `groupby` values, we have to use an `aggregation` function, and I have used `sum`. In case there are 2 `non-null` values for any `id`, then the will be summed up. If `id` could have multiple `non-null` values, then it's bettwe to use `min/max`, so that we get one of the values rather than `sum`.

```
df1=sqlContext.sql(
    'select id, max(value) over (partition by id) as value from table_view'
)
```

Comment: thanks, but actually I am manipulating an intermediate table, it has more than 70 columns and 20 million rows, is it efficient to do it with a SQL on the whole table?

Comment: Oh yes, why not. SQL uses it's own in built optimizations. I will definitely use it. But, you can do your own time testing as well. Mind it, my code assumes that you have only one `non-null` value for any particular `id`, else it would sum them up. When you are grouping values, you need to provide an aggregation function, and I have provided `sum.`

Comment: If any of the two answers has helped you, you can always upvote them and accept the one which you feel like.